# Pandas highlight rows based on index name

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have been struggling with how to style highlight pandas rows based on index names. I know how to highlight selected rows but when I have to highlight based on the index, the code is not working.

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': list('ABCD'), 'value': range(4)})
print(df)
  key  value
0   A      0
1   B      1
2   C      2
3   D      3
```

**Highlight rows when key has value 'B' or 'D'**

```
# this works

    df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' 
                                          if (x.key == 'B' or x.key == 'D')
                                      else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```

**Highlight rows based on index names**

```
# This DOES NOT work
df1 = df.set_index('key')
df1.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' 
                                      if (x.index == 'B' or x.index == 'D')
                                      else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```

How to highlight the rows based on index names?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `index` to `name`:

```
df1.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' 
                                  if (x.name == 'B' or x.name == 'D')
                                  else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```

---

[image: pic]

Comment: What to do when we have a column called 'name' ?

Comment: @astro123 - then select by `x['name']`